# Get the color code of a selected slice in HighCharter R

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts, shinyapps, r-highcharter

I'm trying to develop a part of a shiny app that makes an interactive visualization between a pie chart and a world map. So I want the users to click on the pie chart and then I can get the selected slice and the color code of the corresponding slice. I'm able to take the the slice that has been selected by the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

ui <- fluidPage(
    column(3,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "300px")
    ),
    column(3,
           textOutput("clicked")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){

    click_js <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('pieclick',event.point.name);}")

    output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
        highchart() %>% 
            hc_chart(type = "pie") %>% 
            hc_add_series(data = list(
                list(y = 3, name = "cat 1"),
                list(y = 4, name = "dog 11"),
                list(y = 6, name = "cow 55"))) %>% 
            hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = click_js)))
    })

    output$clicked <- renderText({
        input$pieclick
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I can't see any way on how I can get the corresponding color of the selected slice ?

A possible solution for that is if I can get a vector of all the slice and a vector of all the corresponding color-codes then I can make a comparison between the value I got from the selection and the colors of each value. I also couldn't find a way to get all the values and color-codes used automatically in the pei chart generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hey, the `event.point` has loads of other data, one of which is the `event.point.color` which we can take out. Do print out the object or event using `console.log(event)` so you can see what other things you can use from the event...
- We can also ask for the hex color code from the point you're clicking within the same event. I couldn't find it how to use it seamlessly using purely `JS`, so going to do it on the R side...
- Then we are going to convert the hex to human readable color using `plotrix` package. May need to remove digits of some colors like: `grey27` and so on, so will just `gsub` and remove the digits

---

```
library(shiny)
library(plotrix)
library(highcharter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,
         highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "300px")
  ),
  column(3,
         textOutput("clicked")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  click_js <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('pieclick',[event.point.name,event.point.color]);}")
  
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "pie") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list(
        list(y = 3, name = "cat 1"),
        list(y = 4, name = "dog 11"),
        list(y = 6, name = "cow 55"))) %>% 
        hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = click_js)))
  })
  
  output$clicked <- renderText({
    req(input$pieclick)
    d <- input$pieclick
    mycolor <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", color.id(d[2])[1])
    paste0(d[1],"-",mycolor)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.Is there a way I can get a full map of the colors and categories without clicking ? 
The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to interconnect pei chart with a world map and get a some color from pie to the be pinned point in the world map. So if none of the slices of the pei chart is chosen, I want to show everything on the world map with the same color as pei chart color pattern.

Comment: So, the `highcharter` package has `hc_colors()` function call, and uses colors from `library(viridisLite)`, you can have a look at these ones. Note that by default they will loop around if your pie chart has a lot of categories...